# How to set location to a custom tile overlay

Tags: android, overlay, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to add an image overlay to google map like in the [Google IO 2013](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/) app. 
The map should look like this. 
[image] 
I have two questions
 1. how to implment custom tileproviver for google maps android
 2. How to set the location of the tile provider

Comment: did get the working solution?

Comment: @AlexChengalan not yet

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("YOUR TITLE");
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
```

try the ".addMarker"